# Exchange Kerberos Token for Authentication Code with Azure AD

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, kerberos, windows-authentication

### The Question

I have a way to get my Kerberos Token.  I need a `curl` command to send to Azure AD (including the Kerberos Token) to get it to call my callback URL with the Authentication Code. (Which I will then do another call with to get a JWT Access Token.)

### What I have Tried

I have tried googling for what this `curl` command would be, but I can't seem to find anything definitive.

With another IDP (WSO2), I am able to send in a normal request to authenticate without any user information included in the request.  That then sends back a `WWW-Authenticate` header asking me to negotiate authentication.  I then send in a `Authentication` header with `Negotiate {Kerberos Token}` as the value.  This then calls my callback URL with the Authorization Code.  But neither of these are working with Azure AD.

When I send the first request to Azure AD, I get back a HTML for a login page (rather than the request to negotiate with my Kerberos token).  WSO2 has a way to indicate in the request what it calls a "realm".  This let me indicate that I wanted to use the integrated security route with it.  I have not found a similar syntax with Azure AD.

**What is the syntax of the request(s) needed to send in a Kerberos token and get back a Authorization Code?**

NOTE: I am not actually going to use the `curl` command, but having that will allow me to integrate what it does into my code.

Comment: The bounty attracted a [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) plagiariser.

Comment: To be clear, that answer has now been deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's really the OAuth way to do things. A client should not know about particular authentication protocols or deal with credentials as part of its application code.

**CODE FLOW APPROACH**

The OAuth 2.0 and OpenID Connect solution is for the client to redirect to an authorization server (AS) using a [code flow](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#CodeFlowSteps). The AS then runs a Kerberos based authentication method. This is managed via browser redirects.

**KERBEROS OAUTH FLOW**

Typically a cloud AS like Azure AD would redirect to an on-premise identity provider (IDP) that supports standards based authentication such as SAML or OIDC, and would also be able to interact with an on-premise Kerberos / LDAP store, such as Active Directory.

This type of flow has to involve the system browser, since user credentials must be externalized from clients as a core principle of OAuth 2.0.

The last time I integrated this flow, browsers had preconditions where the IDP domain name had to be in the Local Intranet zone in order for the browser to automatically send the user's Kerberos ticket.

If the user was outside the work network this resulted in a challenge where a form was presented and the credentials needed to be manually entered.

**SUMMARY**

Kerberos based logins are widely used with OAuth 2.0, though there are caveats, now that people increasingly operate outside work networks.

Depending on the IT setup. Azure AD may also be able to act as the IDP. Be aware that there are two flows though. First, a code flow from the app to the AS. Second, the AS integrates with the IDP, which does the Kerberos integration work.